# How to Recalculate formula field on real time in vf page

Tags: visualforce, formula-field

Is there anyway to force an object to recalculate it's formula fields, either through standard or extended controllers in visualforce page(Mostly using action:suppot).
        While googling i found in Winter 16 release recalculateFormulas()  method is introduced.. But i dont know how to use it. Has anybody used this method.

Answer (score 4):

To get the updated values for a formula you have two choices:

1. Do a DML and update the record, then require for the values
2. In winter 16 you can use recalculateFormulas()...

i.e Suppose the formula field `fField__c` on Account is the first three characters of the name.

```
Account a = [Select ID, Name, fField__c From Account where.....];
a.Name = '123AAAAAAAA';
a.recalculateFormulas();
system.assertEquals('123',a.fField__c);
```

The `recalculateFormulas()` method acts on an sObject to recalculate the formulas for the specific sObject without having to do a DML. The change is not persisted to the database though unless you do a dml.

> Recalculates all formula fields on an sObject, and sets updated field
>   values. Rather than inserting or updating objects each time you want
>   to test changes to your formula logic, call this method and inspect
>   your new field values. Then make further logic changes as needed

Comment: Additional note: This method doesn’t recalculate cross-object formulas. If you call this method on objects that have both cross-object and non-cross-object formula fields, only the non-cross-object formula fields are recalculated.

Comment: @Himanshu - While you may be correct, the documentation does not state that. is says **all** formula fields. Although there are lots of undocumented exceptions as we know. I have not tested it so YMMV

Comment: You may be correct too. It is mentioned in usages section https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_recalculateFormulas

Comment: @Himanshu - Great point and you are correct. Thanks for the info on the clickthrough....